# How translate /YYYY/MM/DD/ URL path to non-Gregorian calendars?

Tags: scala, url, localization, internationalization, playframework-2.0

I'm developing a blog hosting service, and blog articles can be reached via URLs like
`http://server/2012/10/30/article-title`. How do I best handle the `/YYYY/MM/DD/` part of the URL for countries where people prefer a non-Gregorian calendar?

(For example, would people in Islamic countries prefer that I translate `/2012/10/15` to `/1425/Muharram/15/`? (That'd be the current date, in the Islamic calendar).)

(Update: Platform and language: Play Framework 2 and Scala, and some AngularJs Javascript.)

---

Update 2: What I did, based on the answers and comments below, was removing the date completely from the URL. Instead e.g. blog articles will be reachable via e.g. `http://server/blog/-3kqf8-article-title`, where `3kqf8` is the blog post ID in the database. Thanks!

Comment: What platform? What language? Why not simply have a single format that is time based but not calendar based?

Comment: What if there are two calendars that both have purely numeric forms that look like '/dddd/dd/dd/' (where `d` = digit)? How are you going to know which type of URL this is?

Comment: @Oded Platform: Play Framework 2, language: Scala. (How does it matter by the way? For the URL? :-))

Comment: So, you are saying this is not a programming question?

Comment: @Oded wrote "Why not simply have a single format that is time based" — I don't quite understand what you have in mind. Is it something like `http://server/43563856/article-title`, where 43563856 is the number of milliseconds since 1970?

Comment: That's one possible example, a Unix epoch (though you can be much less granular than having 1 second resolution). Or you could have a sequence. I can't help but think you are asking for a solution for a problem that is not there.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, I also wonder about that. Perhaps if the blog artitle text is in English, then people would assume `/dddd/dd/dd` is a Gregorian date, and if the text is in Arabic, then Arabic readers would realize that the Hijri calendar is being used. — But I suppose that in some cases the `/dddd/dd/dd` format would cause confusion.

Comment: Even with English you have a problem, as the difference between US and UK date formats can show...

Comment: I would personally just use the ISO date format, as it is designed to be appropriate for use with computers (e.g. lexicographic and chronological order match).  You should worry about localized date formatting _in the text and display_, not in the URL.  The URL could be cafjFHDH721fav772D0x and it would be just as good for most everyone.  If not, having Latin characters and not Arabic script for Farsi or whatever is probably a bigger deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the URL itself, I would use whatever scheme was convenient for me.

As for formatting the date within the page, that could be easily accommodated along with other Locale-sensitive issues with a library that supports the Islamic calendar. You didn't mention what the environment is you're building this in, but a google search for 'islamic calendar for x' ought to help bunches.

If you want to maintain multiple forms for the URL, that would be possible but obviously comes at the price of more complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You might look up ICU4J, which includes a reworking of java.util.Calendar with an IslamicCalendar subclss.

I've not used these, but they seem straightforward (if you are already comfortable with the awkward java.util.Calendar), and would be easy to work with from Scala/Play.

http://site.icu-project.org

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/Calendar.html

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/util/IslamicCalendar.html

Comment: Thanks, however I wasn't really asking about date time libraries. From your answer it's not clear to how I would actually put those date libraries to use.

Comment: Well, in play you could set up routes like /:year/:month/:day, which would forward to a function that would examine the month, which if a String would be treated as Islamic (per your example above). You'd then use IslamicCalendar to find the appropriate java.util.Date. If month is numeric, you'd use GregorianCalendar to find the same. You'd then call a function which finds the appropriate post based on the day implied by the java.util.Date, regardless of which calendar was parsed to find the day.

Comment: (should have been "if non-numeric", rather than "if a String" above)